# Generate JWToken from salesforce using Consumer Secret

Tags: rest-api, rest, apexrest, jwt

I am trying to connect to an API and based on their requirement, JWToken is required to make a call and the JWToken must be signed using the provided consumer secret.

Now, they have a sample code in python that works well. I just want to know how to make it work with salesforce.

Here's the python code: (i've replaced the consumer id,secret,token and endpoints with random values.)

```
import jwt
import _datetime
import requests

app_consumer_id = "000"
app_consumer_secret = "000"
app_access_token = "0000"
base_url = "https://baseurl.com"
end_point = "/API/endpoint/version/client/"
httpMethod = "GET"

# obtain the uri for the endpoint I'm going to query for
uri = base_url + end_point

# set up the jwt token claims dictionary
claims = {
    "iss": "http://mydomain.com.au",
    "aud": "https://audience.com",
    "nbf": _datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
    "exp": _datetime.datetime.utcnow() + _datetime.timedelta(seconds=60),
    "consumerId": app_consumer_id,
    "accessToken": app_access_token,
    "url": uri,
    "httpMethod": httpMethod
}

# create the base64 encoded JWtoken string as byte code
encoded_jwt_byte = jwt.encode(claims, app_consumer_secret, algorithm='HS256')

# convert the byte code to a string
jwt_str = str(encoded_jwt_byte, 'utf-8')

# create signing headers
headers = {'Authorization': 'JwToken' + ' ' + jwt_str, 'content-type': 'application/json'}

# send the request and obtain the result
response = requests.get(uri, verify=True, headers=headers, timeout=45)

# print the returned json to my console
print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty similar with Salesforce, but your sample code has the parameters incorrect for the platform. See [OAuth 2.0 JWT Bearer Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=5) from the Salesforce documentation for more details. Rather than using the JWT for authorization on REST requests, you'll exchange it for an access token, which you'll then include with a `Bearer` authorization header (if you're constructing your REST requests manually).

I use JWT in Python in one of my projects and have a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/davidmreed/5f4b7b8436487f9da9f682ca97f12cd9) available showing how to use it with `simple_salesforce`. It's short, so I'll include the entirety here:

```python
import jwt
import requests
import datetime
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from simple_salesforce.exceptions import SalesforceAuthenticationFailed

def jwt_login(consumer_id, username, private_key, sandbox=False):
    endpoint = 'https://test.salesforce.com' if sandbox is True else 'https://login.salesforce.com'
    jwt_payload = jwt.encode(
        { 
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(seconds=30),
            'iss': consumer_id,
            'aud': endpoint,
            'sub': username
        },
        private_key,
        algorithm='RS256'
    )

    result = requests.post(
        endpoint + '/services/oauth2/token',
        data={
            'grant_type': 'urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer',
            'assertion': jwt_payload
        }
    )
    body = result.json()

    if result.status_code != 200:
        raise SalesforceAuthenticationFailed(body['error'], body['error_description'])
    
    return Salesforce(instance_url=body['instance_url'], session_id=body['access_token'])
```

Call `jwt_login()` with the consumer Id, username, JWT signing key, and a Boolean for sandbox or production and you'll get back a `simple_salesforce.Salesforce` instance. If you aren't using that library and just want the access token, you could `return body['access_token']` instead and modify the error handling.

N.b. as written this requires Python 3.6 for the time handling.